# Replicate items from list basing on the second list

Tags: list, duplicates, ocaml

Write a function that replicates items in a list based on a second list specifying the number of times items are to be duplicated.

Write the function in Ocaml in a functional way of programming using lists.

If library functions - may be used only with O(1) computational complexity.

---

*For example:*

```
duplicate [5;6;7] [0;2;5;3];;
```

*returns:*

```
[6;6;7;7;7;7;7]
```

---

Code I've invented so far:

```ml
let duplicate (list1, list2)=
let rec read (list2, list1) = 
if List.hd list2 = 0 then read (List.tl list2, List.tl list1) else print (List.hd list2, List.hd list1)
let rec print (acc, num) =
num :: (print (acc-1, num));;
```

---

- First of all, it does not compile, I have "syntax error"...
- I do not feel sure about these "nested" functions.
- I believe that complexity could be better.

Comment: "does not work" is not a very useful problem description. Please be more specific.

Comment: What happens if the first list is longer than the second list?

Comment: let's say, we will not allow this situation. But maybe is it possible to secure the code against such data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are considering an answer to this question, you should examine the most simple case.. i.e. How can I add an element to a list x number of times. Example:

```
let rec add_elem_num_times num times lst =
  match times with
  | 0 -> lst
  | _ -> add_elem_num_times num (times - 1) (num::lst)

let ans = add_elem_num_times 5 3 (add_elem_num_times 3 8 [])

let () = List.iter (fun x -> Printf.printf "%d\n" x) ans
```

The rest is just getting it to work for many elements.

Comment: Well, what if 2 separated lists are needed, as I wrote in question?

Comment: Two separate lists? Well one list will provide the element and the other will provide the number for times. If you look at my solution, you'll note it takes a element and a number(number for times) and both of these values can be obtained from lists.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to write a `zip` function that turns two lists into a list of tuples. `List.combine` does this but requires that both be of the same length.

```
let rec zip lst1 lst2 =
  match lst1, lst2 with
  | [], _ | _, [] -> []
  | x::xs, y::ys -> (x, y) :: zip xs ys
```

Now we can get tuples containing the value and the number of times to repeat it:

```
# zip [5;6;7] [0;2;5;3];;
- : (int * int) list = [(5, 0); (6, 2); (7, 5)]
```

Then we simply need to map over that using `List.init` and `Fun.const` to construct lists of the correct length:

```
# zip [5;6;7] [0;2;5;3]
|> List.map @@ fun (a, b) -> List.init b @@ Fun.const a;;
- : int list list = [[]; [6; 6]; [7; 7; 7; 7; 7]]
```

But we don't want a lists of lists, so we need to flatten this using `List.concat_map` rather than `List.map`:

```
# zip [5;6;7] [0;2;5;3]
|> List.concat_map @@ fun (a, b) -> List.init b @@ Fun.const a;;
- : int list = [6; 6; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7]
```